# Random effects models / Integrate over the random effect

Tags: maximum-likelihood, sas, random-effects-model

I am trying to do maximum likelihood estimation and trying to see if the problem can be formulated using a random effect model. Here is the problem description:

> There are $100$ pairs $(N_i, D_i)$ where each $N_i$ is the number of trials and $D_i$ the number of successes in the $i$-th Binomial experiment (with $100$ trials). The probability $p$ of the binomial depends on the NormCDF through a parameter $\rho$ (which needs to be estimated using MLE). The probability $p$ is really a CONDITIONAL probability, conditional on $y$ = some constant, where $y$ can range over $(0,1)$.
>   Thus, I have a likelihood function $L$ which is being integrated over a variable $y$, $0 < y < 1$. That is,

$L$ = int over $(0,1)$ of Binomial(n,d,p)dy,
 or equivalently,
$L$ = int over $(0,1)$ of $\{ k1 * p^d * (1-p)^ (n-d) dy \},0<y<1$
 where $p$ is  a function of $y$, and $k1$,$n$,$d$ are constants, $k1 = {n \choose d}$.
Also
`p(y) = NORMCDF(  (gamma -  {sqrt(rho)*INVNORMCDF(y)}  ) / sqrt(1-rho)  )`, where gamma is a constant (over all 100 trials).

I am trying to maximize $L$ to obtain an estimate for $\rho$.

I would like to know if I can think of the $y$ as a random effect, and also, if specifying $y$ as a random effect in `SAS proc nlmixed` implies that the likelihood $L$ is automatically integrated over $y$. Currently I am trying to maximize the likelihood in `SAS / IML` and the problem is the optimization for $\rho$ does not work (`IML` just keeps running, and I think it is because the likelihood function is flat enough that convergence takes too long).

I am trying to understand what it means for a variable $y$ to be a random effect: does it mean that the likelihood is integrated over all possible values of $y$? If that is true, can I estimate $\rho$ using `PROC NLmixed` as follows:

`gamma = 0.5;
    PROC NLMIXED DATA=bindata MAXITER=200000 QPOINTS=10 GCONV=1e-15;
    PARMS rho = 0.5;
    * Define likelihood;
    w1 = INVNORMCDF(y);  
    p  = NORMCDF(  (gamma -  sqrt(rho)*w1 ) / sqrt(1-rho)  );
    L  = (n CHOOSE d)*((1-p)**(n-d)) + log(p**d);
    MODEL d ~ GENERAL(L);
    RANDOM y~ NORMAL(0,1) SUBJECT=ID;
    RUN;`

In this way, I don't need to integrate the binomial density over $y$ in $(0,1)$ myself in `IML` using a `QUAD` function as I am doing now.

Comment: Something is going wrong w/ the site's markup / HTML for code formatting. I don't know what it is, but we'll see if we can figure it out.